# Java format GUI output

Tags: java, user-interface, output

If I want to format output in a GUI (specifically having only 2 decimal places for a number), would I use the `DecimalFormat` class along with the `printf()` method, or is there another way of doing this?

Comment: What do you mean by output in a GUI? What GUI library and elements are you using?

Answer (score -1):

Basically you will want to round the number leaving 2 decimal places, or, in other words, round only the digits after the second digit after a decimal point, so:

```
number = Math.round(number * 100)/100;
```

Depending on your exact needs use Math.floor() or Math.ceil()